# Componente no renderiza datos asincronos de Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Estoy intentando renderizar una consulta asincrona en una tabla, pero el componente se renderiza al parecer primero y los datos se reciben mas tarde, lo que hace que la tabla quede vacía en dicho campo:

[image: Tabla con campo categoría vacío]

EL código de la consulta a firebase es el siguiente, teniendo en cuenta que el campo categoría es una referencia. Cabe resaltar que este es un custom hook:

```javascript
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { DB } from "../api/config";
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthContext";

export function useEntriesList() {
  const [entries, setEntries] = useState([]);
  const user = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    DB.collection("registros")
      .where("userId", "==", user.uid)
      .onSnapshot((query) => {
        const docs = [];
        query.forEach((doc) => {
          let item = doc.data();
          item.id = doc.id;
          item.category.onSnapshot((doc) => {
            item.categoryName = doc.data().name;
          });
          docs.push(item);
        });
        setEntries(docs);
      });
  }, []);

  return entries;
```

Finalmente el componente que renderiza los datos que se reciben en el prop es el siguiente:

```javascript
import React from "react";

export default function TableEntries({ datos }) {
  return (
    <>
      {datos.map((doc) => {
        return (
          <tr key={doc.id}>
            <td>{doc.date}</td>
            <td>{doc.type === "exp" ? "Gasto" : "Ingreso"}</td>
            <td>{doc.title}</td>
            <td>{doc.categoryName}</td>
            <td>{doc.value}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

PD: cuando se realiza un `console.log(datos)` del prop datos, este logra renderizar el valor `categoryName`, pero cuando realizo el map sobre dichos datos, este viene como `undefined`.

UPDATE:
Anexo el codigo del componente padre de TableEntries:

```javascript
import React from "react";

import Card from "../../components/Card/Card";
import Table from "../../components/Table/Table";
import TableEntries from "../../components/Table/TableEntries";
import { useEntriesList } from "../../hooks/useEntriesList";
// const TableEntries = lazy(() => import("../../components/Table/TableEntries"));

export default function EntriesList() {
  const entries = useEntriesList();

  return (
    <Card title="Listado de registros">
      <Table
        titles={["Fecha", "Tipo", "Nombre", "Categoria", "Valor", "Acción"]}
      >
        <TableEntries datos={entries} />
      </Table>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Agradezco por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el elemento padre de `TableEntries`?

Comment: @FranAcuna ya realice la actualización. ME confirmas si es necesario los demás componentes padres que son llamados dentro de `TableEntries`. Gracias

Comment: *cuando se realiza un console.log(datos) el prop datos, este logra renderizar el valor* este console log donde lo haces? ¿En `<TableEntries>`?

Comment: Si el `console.log` lo realizo en TableEntries pero por fuera del return (render) del componente. Lo realizo tal cual llegan los datos desde el componente padre, pero cuando realizo el log al `map` ahi me retorna como `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

luego de una investigación y logré identificar el uso de Promises para resolver la asincronia de los datos y que una vez estuviese completo, pudiera renderizar toda la información o el objeto desde Firebase. La solución está en la implementación de una promesa en el segundo query (snapshot) para que una vez este retorne los datos, entonces se realice el set del estado. A continuación el código:

```javascript
useEffect(() => {
    DB.collection("registros")
      .where("userId", "==", user.uid)
      .onSnapshot((query) => {
        const docs = [];
        query.forEach((doc) => {
          let item = doc.data();
          item.id = doc.id;
          const promise = item.category
            .get()
            .then((doc) => ({ ...item, categoryName: doc.data().name }))
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
          docs.push(promise);
        });
        Promise.all(docs).then((doc) => setEntries(doc));
      });
  }, []);
```

Muchas gracias por toda la ayuda.